# Get Zedgraph chart size and location

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using a Zedgraph chart only to use the chart axis as a rulers. I'm adding an image over the graph. The control that hold the image is a PanAndZonPictureBox from OpenCV.

The thing is that I need to position the PictureBox right over the chart region. Is there any property of the Zedgrap control that gives the Graph location and size on the screen?

The final objective is to have a control that displays a image with rulers and I can zoom and pan.